# Javascript pop-up issue when openned from different tabs

Tags: javascript, session

I have openned my application in a Internet explorer tab say "TAB1" , and by clicking a button say "button1" in the "TAB1" , a pop-up say "POP-UP1" will open, in the "POP-UP1" screen if i click a button, it will add some elements in the "TAB1"screen (Parent screen 1) .

Now i open my same application in the another tab say "TAB2" in the same IE browser window and click the "button1" which opens the pop-up in the Same 
"POP-UP1" (because the window.open() function code is same with the same pop-up name). Now when i try to add some elements in the "TAB2" (parent screen 2), But instead of adding to "TAB2", it adds the elements in the "TAB1" screen.

How to write the javascript code to add elements in the correct parent screen from whichever the pop-up is initiated. I want the same pop-up to work for all the tabs openned instead of openning many pop-ups from different tabs.

Please help me.

Comment: Would be nice to see some code like the function you use to open the popup.... (normally "parent.opener" should be enough....)

Comment: Window.open(URL,'mypopup','height=50,width=50')

Comment: Eventhough I use parent.opener it is referring to the TAB1 screen instead of referring to TAB2

Answer (score 0):

I think is because the name of the popped window is the same: 
the parent.opener of the popup is the first tab... so it will always refer to it.

All I can think of is to have a **different popup-name**
for each tab the site is opened.

This way you will have 2(or more) popups and each will refer to his own parent.oopener.

try this :

```
var myTime=new Date().getTime();
var popupName="mypopup_"+myTime;
var myPopup=null;
function popMypopup(URL){
    myPopup=window.open(URL,popupName,"height=50,width=50");
    myPopup.focus();
}
```

> to pop the window use

```
popMypopup('your/url/here.html')
```

Comment: Hi federico...tnk u so much for the info...but I have already suggested this..but we need to do this in single tab. Thts why I posted in stackoverflow...hopefully to get an solution for single window...something like resetting all the paramters of the old popup before opening the new popup on the same window....

Answer (score 0):

You can try to see if the parent opener of the popup refers to the current window... if it doesn't close it and reopen it.

> Something like this:

```
var myPopup=null;
function popMypopup(URL){
        myPopup=window.open(URL,"mypopup","height=50,width=50");
        myPopup.focus();
        if(myPopup.parent.opener!=window){
            myPopup.close();
            popMypopup(URL);
        }
    }
```

PS: only tested on IE ... but I believe it should work on all browsers.